# Shared Domain multidomain trouble

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ftp, hosting

I've got in a ftp in a hosting the following configuration:

```
www/domain2
```

The www corresponds to another domain (domain1), and when I try to access a post in wordpress in domain2 the url looks like this:

```
domain2.com
```

and if I click in a post or an article:

```
domain1.com/domain2.com/postexample
```

How can I configure mod_rewrite so always the url will be like www.domain2.com/postexamle and never show the domain1?

The path that I put the `.htaccess` is `www/domain2/.htaccess` is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Move your `.htaccess` to `/www` with the following

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain2.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # not a dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not a file
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domain2/$1 [L]
```

But, you need to make sure that your article links do not include `domain2` in them. So, they can either be `http://www.domain2.com/some-domain-2-file.php` (absolute) or just `some-domain-2-folder/file.php` (relative).